# laravel: "syntax error, unexpected 'js' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to figure out why this is happening

It shows this syntax error, but I don't understand it

```
<script  src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{url}}` allows you to create "url path". This usage's benefit is you can send data with that. But as i told it is searching url's of js.

If you use `{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}` you are gonna search jquery file in your public directory. Not url. This absolutely work.

Comment: yes it will work, but we don't know him web.php, syntax. Low percentage but still some problem maybe occurs with {{url}}, when calling file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

To

```
 <script src="{{URL::to('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct way is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>:
```